# Integrating Microsoft dynamic 2013 or 2015 with PHP

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Do we have any libraries available to interact with Microsoft dynamic CRM 2013 or Microsoft dynamic CRM 2015 from PHP?

Comment: one way is to interact with the database of the crm

Comment: Another is to use CURL and interact directly with the CRM api.  http://www.cardus.com/2014/08/22/php-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-online/

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/6dg/dynamics-crm-php-connector/

Comment: Also recheck following - [http://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2015/02/soap-only-authentication-using-php.html](http://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2015/02/soap-only-authentication-using-php.html)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no complete library out there for connecting to CRM using PHP.  To connect using PHP you need to use SOAP so if you don't have some knowledge about PHP and/or SOAP you might find it difficult to connect.

As Andrii Butenko commented I highly recommend looking Jason Lattimer's post as he's one of the few people I've seen have a working On Premise IFP sample.
http://jlattimer.blogspot.com.au/2015/02/soap-only-authentication-using-php.html

Once you have that up and running then there is lots of samples out there of basic requests.  I blogged awhile ago about it for CRM2011 however they all still work for newer versions.
http://crmtroubleshoot.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/dynamics-crm-2011-php-and-soap-calls.html

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Dynamics CRM online now has in preview a new API that is fully based on REST. This can easily be used by any client application.

Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm/webapipreview.aspx for details.